# Link Wrapping: what does it actually do?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have the SAP package with Marketing Cloud Enterprise 2.0

I was reading this article (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000248048&type=1) which says:

Account Branding - The Salesforce Marketing Cloud will brand your account with your chosen authenticated domain. This product modifies link and image wrapping and removes all references to the Salesforce Marketing Cloud in favor of your authenticated domain.

What exactly does this mean for a link in an email?

For example, when I read an email sent from SFMC, I hover over a link and it looks like this:

http://cl.s10.exct.net/?qs=0000000000....etc

Is that right? That doesn't seem like it has "removed all references to Salesforce Marketing Cloud" as stated above.

Any clarity on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAP wraps you domains or hyperlinks and images etc with a domain of your brand choice. E.g. if my company was ACME Corp, then I might want a SAP of e.acme.com

I would register the domain and point DNS records to salesforce name servers. Salesforce will need to configure backend SAP to your business unit. When I then send an email, my hyperlinks would show as click.e.acme.com (for example)

If you are getting a URL of http://cl.s10.exct.net/?qs=0000000000....etc then SAP has not been correctly configured on your business unit. If you have correctly delegated your domain to Salesforce, then raise a support request to have them assign the SAP branding to your necessary business units.

Things to note - 
1) you can only have 1 SAP per business unit
2) you can share the same SAP across multiple business units
3) if you create a new business unit then you will need to raise a support case to have the SAP applied